# How to acquire sqlform's field dynamically in web2py

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web2py

my table:

```
db.define_table('problem',
                Field('title','string',unique=True,length=255),
                Field('description','text',notnull=False,default=''),
                Field('in_date','datetime',notnull=False,default=request.now),
                Field('input','text',notnull=False,default=''),
                Field('result','text',notnull=False,default=''),
                Field('defresult','text',notnull=False),
                Field('submit','integer',notnull=False,default=0),
                Field('solved','integer',notnull=False,default=0),
                Field('pass_rate','decimal(2,2)',notnull=True,default =0.00),
                format = '%(title)s')
```

Insert a record into problem table by sqlform,how to acquire the result field of problem in sqlform dynamically.

```
def test():
    user_id=_get_user_id(auth)
    id=request.args(0,cast=int)
    for row in db(db.belongs.id==id).select():
        taskid=row.task_id
        problemid=row.problem_id
    record=db.problem(problemid) or redirect(URL('index'))
    fields=['title','description','input','result']
    form=SQLFORM(db.problem,record,readonly=False,fields=fields)
    if form.process().accepted:
            db(db.problem.id==problemid).update(submit=db.problem.submit+1)
            if(form.vars.result==db.problem.defresult):
```

The last line I want to judge if the result field is equal to the defresult field. 
The form.vars.result seems not change even I input another value into sqlform and the values insert before have fill the sqlform after I reloading the page. how to clear the sqlform? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.vars.result` does contain the new value. The problem is that in `form.vars.result==db.problem.defresult`, you are comparing that value to a `Field` object rather than to the actual value from the record. Earlier, you have:

```
record=db.problem(problemid)
```

So, your equality test should be:

```
if form.vars.result == record.defresult:
```